# Lightest way to add timestamps in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, time, text-editing, timestamp

What is the lightest way to add a timestamp string within a Notepad++ text document?

The method I know of is to use a plugin that gives Notepad++ Python functionality, and then write a small Python routine to insert a timestamp (in a user-defined format that includes the current time and date) into the text.

After doing that, you can assign a keyboard shortcut to run that Python routine.

That's a lot of overhead and bulk just to insert a timestamp.  Every Notepad++ plugin causes Notepad++ to load a little slower, and can introduce bugs.  Plus, it's another thing to keep up to date.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this in Notepad++?

Comment: A way to insert the current date (not the timestamp !) is to install `Notepad++ Plugin Demo` it contains a command to insert the currentdate (short & long format)

Comment: @Toto Thanks Toto!  Although I need to insert the date and time (using a user-defined format), your tip may be very useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

**This will add the current date time, not the timestamp.**

To insert current date time (using Npp 64-bit), you have to add a plugin.

- Plugins >> Plugins Admin
- Install `Notepad++ Plugin Demo`
- Restart Notepad++

When you want to insert current date time at cursor position:

- Plugins >> `Notepad++ Plugin Demo` >> `Date Time`

You can add a shortcut that runs the command.

---

**From comment:** Thanks to [Ravikumar](https://superuser.com/users/1375352/ravikumar-b)

> Starting from Notepad++ 8.1.5 this functionality is in build no extensions are needed. For more details refer the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72478326/372239

Comment: Starting from Notepad++ 8.1.5  this functionality is in build no extensions are needed. For more details refer the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69551500

Comment: @RavikumarB: Thanks for info, answer updated.